# Global variable turns to be nil after passed a vlaue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Look at the picture below:

[image]

In the method `requestVersionCheckWithAppId`, a network is requested and then the SuccessBlock will be called with the successValue requested back. The block is called on main `thread`.

I came across the problem that the successValue is not `nil`, but when I pass the value to a global variable `store_version`, the variable turns to be `nil`.

I don`t know how does this happen. Any help. Thanks.

-------- Update ----------

May be I made a mistake that I say the value of the variable "store_version" is nil. Although the dashbord shows that the value is nil, I can still print out the value of the variable.

[image]

Comment: Can you actually share the code please?

Comment: I think the class object is deallocated from memory by ARC, and only the block scope will be visible.

post some code please, did you close the view before the request finished ??

Comment: It's an interesting problem.  Add a watchpoint to `store_version` to see if it's being cleared in another thread.

Comment: BTW - `store_version` is not a global variable. It is an instance variable. Big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Create the accessor of your global variable and then try to set the same.

```
@property(strong)NSString *strore_version;
```

Comment: What difference will that make?

Answer (score 0):

parse your id type to string format.

try this

strore_version = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@",successValue];